# How to make interactive slider for user range input in jupyter lab?

Tags: user-interface, jupyter

I'm making POC GUI in jupyter lab. (proof of concept. English is not my language. Does English man use this word, POC?)

One of the main input is range. Some value varX should bigger than minimum value which is user inputed and and varX also smaller than maximum value also user inputed.

So, varX is limited in range.

I'm using package "ipywidgets". in this package, "interact" is good for input a single float, but not beautiful for two float inputs. it show like below.
[image]

I think, if below is possible, much better.(the pic is not real)
[image]

but ipywigets only surport one inputs per one interactive object. so it is impossible.

could you recommend good and beautiful way for gui input for range? in jupyter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stupid.

ipywigets have "range slider"

```
range_slider = widgets.FloatRangeSlider(
    value=[-1., +1.],
    min=-5., max=+5., step=0.1,
    description='xlim:',
    readout_format='.1f',
)
range_slider
```